# Auto Using Configuration of a module in Spring Boot in another

Tags: maven, spring-boot

In my current project i have a class called `CassandraConfiguration` inside my Backend Module to establish a connection to a server. My Backend Module gets used in my core project so of course it has to connect to cassandra to work, too.

The problem is: My Core Project seems not to know about the existence of the `CassandraConfiguration`.

My attempt was to create a class which `extends CassandraConfiguration` but I do not like this solution.

Am I missing something?

Edit:

So this is my Project structure:

I have three modules:

- cassandra
- frontend (requries cassandra)
- rest (requires cassandra)

Both frontend and rest require cassandra, so i put this inside my dependencies in frontend and rest:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>backend-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, since its a spring boot project all of them have spring boot as parent.

INSIDE Cassandra Module is the configuration which i want to reuse in my other modules.

But that does not work automatically. Am I missing something in my maven configuration?

EDIT 2:

I think i found the problem, but not the solution:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>backend-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

simply gets not recognized. Configuration cannot be seen automatically AND when building the project:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project myproject-restful: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Sebas/IdeaProjects/myproject/myproject-restful/src/main/java/de/iutp/myproject/restful/ControlConfiguration.java:[3,49] package myproject.backend.cassandra.config does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Sebas/IdeaProjects/myproject/myproject-restful/src/main/java/myproject/restful/ControlConfiguration.java:[7,43] cannot find symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Spring app you should usually inject dependencies using the `@Autowired` or `@Inject` annotations (they are equivalent, it doesn't really matter which one you use).

For this to work, the class you want to inject must be a Spring component that gets picked up the Spring's context initializer.

You can easily turn any class into a Spring component by annotating it with `@Component`.

And when using Spring Boot, it should then get picked up by the context initializer automatically, ready to be injected into other classes.

Comment: Well, that's the Problem. It doesn't.

Comment: I think you'll have to provide more information in your question then, ideally a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited question